# Static method in the non static context

Tags: java

Is it possible to have a static method in the non static context? I'm just not sure of what the answer is but, I think you can.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Answer is no, but why do you want a static method in the non static context?

Comment: no you cant have static method in a non static context, static method belong to the class not the instance

Comment: That does not sound like something you cannot simply try out on your own.

Comment: @Pirate it was just a question on a examination which I did recently l. So can you have a non static method in the static context?

Comment: Am I misinterpreting the question or something?
I would say "yes, you can call a static method from a non-static context". Lets say you're in an instance method (a non-static context). You can definitely call a static method: `SomeClass.callStaticMethod()`. Or what is meant by `have` in the question? Am I incorrectly interpreting `have` as `call`?

Comment: @Alderath you can call static method from non static method but can't define in non static.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about defining a method in a non-static context. You do not define methods inside other methods, so what does it really mean to define a method within a static or non-static context?

@OP, I think it would be best if you clarified whether by "have" you mean "define" or "call".

Comment: but you can define static members right. like static int a;

Comment: Why on earth is this q getting a negative status? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so. Since you haven't created an object, the non-static method doesn't exist yet and a static method always exists.So you can not call an existing method from a non existing context.

Comment: you can call that static method using class name.

Comment: This answer is talking about non-static method in static context. This is the opposite of what is talked about in the question...